# Possible to use a variadic functions/templates in this way?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I was wondering whether given the below constraints, it is possible to use variadic functions/templates in order to pass a variable number of parameters (which are themselves a return value of a function) into a variadic function.

### Constraints:

1. No STL/Boost/other libraries.
2. No loops/recursion.
3. C++17 or earlier compliant (nothing beyond C++17).

### Brief example:

```
using fn = F(...);
fn* func = (fn*) addr;
value = (*func)(pop_t(outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize)...);
push_t(outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize, value);
```

`fn*` is a function pointer (converted from a known user-defined memory address of a function) which takes in a variable number of pop_t arguments (values poped from a stack), these values (outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize) are static and do not need to be variadic themselves.  Essentially I was wondering whether it's possible to have the pop_t function repeat a variable number of times either A.) by depending on the appropriate number of arguments `fn` is capable of taking in or B.) using a user-defined integer specifying the number of repeats.

As an example say the user were to input a sin or atan2 function, these two functions take different numbers of parameters respectively being sin(x) and atan(y,x). For these two respective functions the function call expressions would look like the following:

```
sin -> (*func)(pop_t(outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize)); 

atan2 -> (*func)(pop_t(outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize),pop_t(outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize));
```

Functions with N arguments pop N values from the stack by calling `pop_t` N times.

### Reproducible example:

```
template<class U, class I>
U pop_t(U* stack, I &stackidx, I &stacksize) {
    if(stacksize>0) {
        stacksize--;
        stackidx = stackidx--;
        return stack[stackidx];
    }
    else {
        return stack[stackidx];
    }
}

int main() {
    float outputstack[2] = {3.141/2,1};
    int o_stackidx = 2;
    int o_stacksize = 2;
    long addr = (long)&atan2;
    using fn = float(...);
    fn* func = (fn*) addr;
    // Unknown variadic function pointer
    float value = (*func)(pop_t(outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize,nt)...);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your description is a little unclear to me. Could you add the code that you would like to be able to write at the call site? i.e. can you show exactly how you would use such a function if it were available?

Comment: @cigien The assignment of value would be the call site of said function..  As an example say the user were to input a sin or atan2 function, these two functions take different numbers of parameters respectively being sin(x) and atan(y,x). For these two respective functions the function call expressions would look like the following:
sin -> (*func)(pop_t(outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize));
atan2 -> (*func)(pop_t(outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize),pop_t(outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize));
Functions with N arguments pop N values from the stack by calling pop_t N times. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself, not as a comment. Also, your description is still unclear, e.g. what is `pop_t`? Try to make a [mre], except for the function that you can't write, of course.

Comment: @cigien Have just added those :) thanks for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to repeat a statement multiple times based on the number of parameters, in that case, you can take help of C++ templates:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <size_t N>
struct repeater {
    template <typename F, typename ...Args>
    static void do_work(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
        f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        repeater<N - 1>::do_work(f, args...);
    }
};

template <>
struct repeater<0> {
    template <typename F, typename ...Args>
    static void do_work(F&&, Args&&...) {}
};

template <size_t N, typename F, typename ...Args2>
void repeat_for_n(F&& to_rep, Args2&&... args) {
    repeater<N>::do_work(to_rep, args...);
}

template <typename T1, typename ...Args1, typename F, typename ...Args2>
void repeat_for_args(T1(Args1...), F&& to_rep, Args2&&... args) {
    repeat_for_n<sizeof...(Args1)>(to_rep, args...);
}
```

And then you can use it like so:

```cpp
repeat_for_args(some_function, [&]() {
    (*func)(pop_t(outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize))
});
```

In case you'd like to try it out yourself first:

**Edit 1:** To generate a function pointer type with `N` repeating types in the parameter with the help of templates, you can do this:

Firstly, you need to define this helper class:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template <typename, typename>
struct make_sig_from_tuple;

template <typename R, typename ...Args>
struct make_sig_from_tuple<R, std::tuple<Args...>> {
    using type = R(*)(Args...);
};

template <typename R, typename ...Args>
using make_sig_from_tuple_t = typename make_sig_from_tuple<R, Args...>::type;
```

And then we can do this,

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct generate_sig_impl {
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<std::tuple<T>&>(), std::declval<typename generate_sig_impl<T, N - 1>::type&>()));
};

template <typename T>
struct generate_sig_impl<T, 0> {
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template <typename R, typename T, size_t N>
struct generate_sig {
    using type = make_sig_from_tuple_t<R, typename generate_sig_impl<T, N>::type>;
};

template <typename R, typename T, size_t N>
using generate_sig_t = typename generate_sig<R, T, N>::type;
```

Now it is possible to use it to cast variadic functions with just the value of `N` without having to explicitly state the arguments in the type multiple times:

```cpp
repeat_for_args(reinterpret_cast<generate_sig_t<float, float, 3>>(function_with_variadic_arguments), /* ... */);
// Equivalent to: repeat_for_args(reinterpret_cast<float(*)(float, float, float)>(function_with_variadic_arguments), /* ... */);
```

**Edit 2:** As the OP in the comments wants to reverse the order of the parameters as well, one can use this:

```cpp
template <typename Arg1, typename ...Args>
struct reverse_func_sig_impl {
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<typename reverse_func_sig_impl<Args...>::type&>(), std::declval<std::tuple<Arg1>&>()));
};

template <typename Arg1>
struct reverse_func_sig_impl<Arg1> {
    using type = std::tuple<Arg1>;
};

template <typename>
struct reverse_func_sig;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct reverse_func_sig<R(Args...)> {
    using type = make_sig_from_tuple_t<R, typename reverse_func_sig_impl<Args...>::type>;
};

template <typename FuncPtr>
using reverse_func_sig_t = typename reverse_func_sig<FuncPtr>::type;
```

Then use it like this:

```cpp
repeat_for_args(reinterpret_cast<generate_sig_t<int(float, int)>>(function_with_variadic_arguments), /* ... */);
// Equivalent to: repeat_for_args(reinterpret_cast<int(int, float)>(function_with_variadic_arguments), /* ... */);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/1Td7GerMo)

Comment: Awesome, that does look along the lines of what I was looking for.  I assume you don't think it can be done without the for loop ?

Comment: @Nullpoint Yes, it can be done. Give me a minute.

Comment: for a bit of context I'm working from within a GPU kernel so using STL is also off the table unfortunately.

Comment: I think the last hurdle is that I'm trying to load arbitrary functions as pointers from (long) addresses, w.r.t your example (https://godbolt.org/z/e7exboKzE) would be something that I'd like to do (if it's even possible?)  Cheers :D

Comment: @Nullpoint `repeat_for_args(fn, ...);` doesn't make sense as `fn` is a type, did you mean: `repeat_for_args(func, ...)`?

Comment: Yes I did mean `repeat_for_args(func, ...)` sorry about that!

Comment: This (https://godbolt.org/z/sP1Y18aos) is probably more along the lines of what I was trying to see could be done; whether a variadic function pointer alias can be used. I imagine a parameter might have to be implemented to tell `repeat_for_args` how many parameters to unpack?

Comment: @Nullpoint If you want, you could cast the function to the number of arguments you need: `repeat_for_args(reinterpret_cast<float(*)(float)>(func), ...)` would hint the compiler to treat the function as if it had only one parameter. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bqGE1ooj5).

Comment: The goal that I was trying to accomplish was to avoid having to use a switch statement for defining the number of args such that the function pointers were completely abstract generic and only user-imposed/defined at run-time.  (Hence using addresses to functions that a user would supply along with an integer N that the user may give at runtime to specify the number of args their function pointer takes in).

Is there a way to reinterpret_cast generically say for N floats given by the number N (I guess that could just be a templated version with <N> args)?

Comment: @Nullpoint I edited the answer. Look at it now.

Comment: That pretty much did it! Thanks a lot!  As a bit of an addon/aside, how could one go about reversing the order of arguments (i.e. if you want the first call to pop_t to be the last argument in the function pointer)?

Comment: @Nullpoint Are you talking about reversing the order of the types of the parameters in the function signature?

Comment: The pop_t statement changes the values of the stackidx and stacksize parameters it takes in (as it's a naive implementation of a stack), thus the order of calling pop_t determines which values are popped from the stack and hence:

v1 = pop_t(a,b,c)
v2 = pop_t(a,b,c)
v1 and v2 are not equal since the indexes b and c change during evaluation of pop_t.

Comment: @Nullpoint I have added it now, you can look at it if you want.

Comment: So I have just tried to implement a test (https://godbolt.org/z/aWTWsjjqv), and for some reason using the ordinary function pointers work fine but not their variadic aliases, i.e. value1 is a valid result of cos(pi) but value isn't... I would have thought the reinterpret_cast would have fixed the arbitrary number of arguments but it looks like it may not have?

Comment: @Nullpoint It's happening because the variadic function isn't able to determine the size of the arguments passed to it, try doing: `value = (*reinterpret_cast<float(*)(float)>(func))(pop_t(outputstack,o_stackidx,o_stacksize));` instead. Moreover, `cos` actually is the overload that accepts `double`, what you want is `cosf`. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Tcsb673zP).

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, also I saw your other comment about use of longs for mem addresses, which I completely agree with, this is just a test stage at the moment and I haven't actually begun the full implementation of this into my project.  

So from what I gather since you have to impose the number of floats in the reinterpret cast at compile-time, it looks like what I'm trying to do might not be possible then?  I mean what I am trying to do is probably fairly dangerous anyway in that I'm trying to let users define their functions with number of parameters at runtime using memory.